# Alpine linux, making a custom ISO image

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

Tried to build rescue iso by following

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image

(used `alpine-extended-3.4.3-x86.iso` installed onto hdd before that)

When booting newly created image, it complains immediately after boot prompt.
What should I do to create proper ISO image?

[image: boot screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If you haven't already delete any old `.iso` files and `isotmp.xxx` directory)

Before the `make PROFILE=alpine-rescue iso` command, run `abuild-keygen -a` and copy the `xxx.rsa.pub` file into `/etc/apk/keys`.

Comment: did you snip the output? It doesn't look like you deleted the isotmp.xxx directory?